# HAProxy configuration file

Tags: networking, centos, unix, proxy, haproxy

Where it is located? Sometimes I see it under `/etc/haproxy.conf`, other times at `/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg`. IF both reside, which one precedes then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at haproxy manual, you can read:

```
haproxy  -f  <configuration file> other options...
```

So, the config file is not optional. It has to be specified when haproxy is started. So, you need to check your startup file such as `/etc/init.d/haproxy`.

Answer (score 0):

my configuration as of the moment resides on /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg.

just run the config using proper permissions.

> sudo haproxy -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg